# Suppose $L$ and $M$ are two vector spaces, how to find a basis of $L+M$ and $L \cap M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(1+t−t^3,1+t+t^2,1−t)$ and $(t^3+t,2−t^3,2+t^3)$ be two basis of subspaces $L$ and $M$.

Find one basis of $L+M$ and $L\cap M$.

I think $(1+t−t^3,\,1+t+t^2,\,1−t)$ could probably be expressed as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & t & t^2 & t^3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \phantom{-}1 & 1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
  \phantom{-}1 & 1 &           -1 \\
  \phantom{-}0 & 1 & \phantom{-}0 \\
            -1 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $(t^3+t,2−t^3,2+t^3)$ could be expressed as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & t & t^2 & t^3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \phantom{-}2 & 2 \\
 1 & \phantom{-}0 & 0 \\
 0 & \phantom{-}0 & 0 \\
 1 &           -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But I am stuck then.

Comment: Hey. What are your thoughts on this problem so far? You can include your thoughts in your post by editing it.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the basis $(1+t−t^3,1+t+t^2,1−t)$ by the more convenient basis

$$(2−t^3,t^3+t^2,1−t)$$

and replace $(t^3+t,2−t^3,2+t^3)$ by

$$(1,t,t^3)$$

It follows that $M\cap L$ contains at least $1-t,2-t^3$ and since $L\neq M$ (for example, because $t^3+t^2$ doesn't lie in the span of $(1,t,t^3)$), it follows that $\dim (L\cap M)$ must equal $2$, that is $(1-t,2-t^3)$ is a basis for $L\cap M$. To find a basis for $L+M$ you can start with the set of generators $(2-t^3,t^3+t^2,1-t,1,t,t^3)$ and eliminate redundant generators to get a basis $$(1,t,t^2,t^3)$$

Indeed, $2-t^3,1-t$ are already in the span of $(1,t,t^3)$ so the only non redundant generator is $t^3+t^2$ which can be replaced by $t^2$ since $t^3$ is already in the basis. Since $1,t,t^2,t^3$ is linearly independent it is a basis of $L+M$. It can be deduced that it is linearly independent from the equality $\dim(L+M)=\dim M+\dim L-\dim(L\cap M)=3+3-2=4$, too.

Comment: Why can you replace the bases in that way? For example, if $ u = a (1+t-t^3) + b (1+t+t^2) + c ( 1-t) $, then with the new basis (2-t^3, t^3+t^3, 1-t), $ u = (a+b)(2-t^3) + b(t^3+t^2) + (a+b+c)(1-t) $, which leads to that  a  = -b in all cases, does it still cover all the situations?